# How to send in codeigniter 4 an email to a default address through a form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been looking at the documentation and found this:

```
    $email = \Config\Services::email();

$email->setFrom('your@example.com', 'Your Name');
$email->setTo('someone@example.com');
$email->setCC('another@another-example.com');
$email->setBCC('them@their-example.com');

$email->setSubject('Email Test');
$email->setMessage('Testing the email class.');

$email->send();
```

I have searched a lot of information on google about it but I only see tutorials on how to send emails via smtp with a mail domain, this is not what I am looking for because I do not have it, I have an email created by a client on a platform and this requires that you send all the data from that form to the mail that has the.

How do I do to send the information from a form to the email?

I have this form:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url() ?>/save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="InputForName" value="<?= set_value('user_name') ?>" placeholder="Nombre y apellidos">
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="InputForEmail" value="<?= set_value('user_email') ?>" placeholder="Email">
                    </div>
                    <div class="buttonHolder">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info text-center">Enviar</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

and I have tried in my controller that formerly already saved in the database everything that was introduced in the form to place this code of the mail, but it does not work always jumps to the else option, therefore I imagine that something must be wrong or maybe this is not the right way.

```
public function save()
    {
        //include helper form
        helper(['form']);
        //set rules validation form
        $rules = [
            'name'          => 'required|min_length[3]|max_length[100]',
            'email'         => 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[100]|valid_email|is_unique[users.user_email]'
        ];

        if ($this->validate($rules)) {
            $model = new UserModel();
            $data = [
                'user_name'     => $this->request->getVar('name'),
                'user_email'    => $this->request->getVar('email')
            ];

            $email = \Config\Services::email();

            $email->setFrom($data['user_email'], $data['user_name']);
            $email->setTo('clientemail@email.com');
            /*$email->setCC('another@another-example.com');
            $email->setBCC('them@their-example.com');*/

            $email->setSubject('lorem ipsum '.$data['user_name'].' lorem ipsum');
            $email->setMessage($data['user_name'].' lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum'.$data['user_email']);

            $email->send();

            $model->save($data);
            //return redirect()->back(); //misma pagina
            return redirect()->to('/{locale}/gracias');
        } else {
            return redirect()->back(); //misma pagina
        }
    }
```

Can someone explain to me how to do what I am trying to do? Thank you !!!!

Comment: "_I have been looking at the documentation_" Which documentation have you been reading?

Comment: Has something changed to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74558785/codeigniter-4-send-data-from-a-form-to-2-emails/74558855#comment131614765_74558855)? Don't double post

Comment: I have looked right here
https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/email.html#sending-email

Comment: The question is different, it's about how to send two emails in one and how to make the email sending work in the other.

Comment: That's documentation for CI3, CI4 email documentation is at https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html Most likely also solves your other question if you use code for your actual CI version. Has also already been mentioned in your other question

Comment: I have edited the question with the new CI4 data, as I don't quite understand or know how to place it properly, I imagine that /app/config/email.php should not be configured, that is to say that this new information goes in a controller. I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong but it still doesn't work.